# Search and replace nth column using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How can we search and replace "xyz" in col3 only?

```
col1,col2,col3,col4  
abc,def,xyz,xyz  
xyz,abc,def,xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk -F , '{ if ($3 == "xyz") $3="abc";}1' OFS=, test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you want to replace it with so I'm just going to use `ghi` as a placeholder:

If that is the actual text then the easiest way is with `sed`. You can do it with `awk` but that will only send the modification to standard output whereas `sed` can change the file itself which is explained below:

```
sed '2s|xyz|ghi|1' file
```

To explain:

```
2s replaces instances on the second line
xyz is what you want to replace
ghi is what it's being replaced with
1 replaces the first instance of it on the specified line
```

The output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
abc,def,ghi,xyz
xyz,abc,def,xyz
```

Once you're sure that it does what you want, use the `-i` switch to change the file itself instead of sending it to standard output:

```
sed -i '2s|xyz|ghi|1' file
```

If there are other lines and columns where you might want to replace it, you'll need to modify `2s` and `1` to specify the location(s) and instance(s). Obviously, you'd also replace `ghi` with whatever replacement you'd like.

If there are other lines in column 3 where you need to replace `xyz`, you can use the `e` switch. For example:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
abc,def,xyz,xyz
xyz,abc,def,xyz
abc,def,xyz,abc
```

`xyz` appears in the fourth line of column 3 as well.

```
sed -e '2s|xyz|ghi|1' -e '4s|xyz|ghi|1' file

sed -i -e '2s|xyz|ghi|1' -e '4s|xyz|ghi|1' file
```

That would replace the first instance on the fourth line as well using `-e` to specify each stream of replacements. The `-i` switch changes the file instead of only sending it to standard input.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk -F ',' -v needle='xyz' -v replacement='foobar' 'BEGIN{ OFS = FS; } (NR > 1 && $3 == needle) { $3 = replacement; } 1' input.txt
```

Set `needle` and `replacement` as required. `NR > 1` ensures that no replacement happens in the first row (apparently containing the column headers).